# MVC: Where do I place custom UICollectionCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, model-view-controller

I'm new in developing on mobile world and I have an architectural question for my project:

where is the correct place for a customized UICollectionViewCell?
Instinctively I would place it under (**V**)iew.

## edit

I would use it in this way:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
  var customCell: CustomCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(CustomCell.identifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell
  customCell.setupWithSomeOtherObject(..)
  return customCell;            
}
```

Comment: it depends, actually... if the cells does not do anything with the _model_ layer directly and it is populated by another class from the _controller_ layer to show values only, it is on the _view_ layer then. if your cell directly connects to the _model_ layer and makes changes of that directly, it would be more likely on the _controller_ layer then – but basically a `...ViewCell` should be clearly on the _view_ layer only.

Comment: @holex, true. Another question is, is it really correct to make *model* changes directly in the cell ..

Comment: @flashadvanced, not a good practice, because if the _model_ layer is updated (for any reason) the _view_ layer should not be affected at all. if you are the only person who works on a project, you can rearrange it relatively quickly, but when you are working in a team, and your job is managing the _view_ layer, and your teammate's job is the _model_ layer; you would not want to get extra job (while you would not like to give extra job to anyone) after a simple update of any layer which should not be connected directly. that is experience and humble opinion. :)

Answer (score 2):

The right place to put a custom `UICollectionViewCell` is your view group, because a cell **is** a view, it is subclassing `UIView`, so yes, this is the right place for it.

Comment: the actual fact of the inheritance does not really defines that clearly, but its connection to the _model_ layer does as the _view_ layer has no direct connection to the _model_ it is always happening via a _controller_ layer's item. if there is such connection, the cell is mostly on _controller_ layer then (we can debate about whether it is good or bad architecture), but logically that would be its place in this 3-way 'relationship'.

Answer (score 1):

To directly answer your question UICollectionViewCell should land in View.

If you are new to mobile developing I'll strongly suggest learn what is MVVM model and how you could adopt it to iOS. The main problem with MVC is that eventually everything ends up in ViewController subclasses. Also MVVM has benefits when testing your code(yep you'll eventually need this too). Of course MVVM is not a holy grail but you could definitely give it a chance.

Nice article to start is:
[MVVM](http://www.objc.io/issue-13/mvvm.html)

Comment: thanks for mentioning MVVM, that I've already seen and I think a lot of people will moves in that direction!

Comment: @SirDeveloper, I personally would not recommend MVVM, it is relatively much harder to maintain in long term, and that is really resource-sensitive; on an iOS it would not be a wise choice.

Answer (score 1):

MVC is a big structure to answer your question. But I will try;

Let's suppose you are going to make a basic photo gallery.

You need a **(M)** odel for your objects let's say it s Photo model and it has name, createdDate sth. This model just keep some info to your app.

You need a **(V)** iew to show some visual things to user. Like *ImageView* to show your image, like **UICollectionView** so **UICollectionView** is a view. And also **UICollectionViewCell** is a view inside of **UICollectionView** . Also you can add another view to your cell.

You need a **(C)** ontroller to manage and control this view and model. For example you keep a file path of image in your Photo object, now you want to show it in **UICollectionViewCell** inside of **UICollectionView** .

So your answer UICollectionViewCell must be inside your Views. 
In **MVC** all controls must be in **Controller** avoid your actions inside view. You should give **delegate** to **controller** via **UICollectionView**